# Intellij does not find main class of java project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a simple code with a main class, but it is not identified by ide, I am not identifying the problem.

Main.java

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileReader leitor = new FileReader("config.txt");
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(leitor, 2 * 1024 * 1024);
    String linha = buffer.readLine();
    while (linha != null) {
        System.out.print(linha+"\n");
        linha = buffer.readLine();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I can't select the main class

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intellij did not recognize the `java` folder as a source folder.

I guess, you did not import the project as a maven project. Checkout the [import maven project guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_import_project_start).

To fix this quickly, you can right click on the `java` folder, select `Mark Directory as` and choose `Sources Root`.